# How to create a model by specifying the field names of the Foreign key that are unique together rather than it's pk?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to configure REST framework serializer to POST a `Target` object by specifying the 3 field names of it's Foreign relation `Market` that are unique together (symbol, exchange, type), rather than specifying the primary keys of the `Market` object.

**models.py**

```
class Exchange(models.Model):
    exid = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)


class Market(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='market')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['symbol', 'type', 'exchange']


class Target(models.Model):
    weight = models.FloatField()
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target')
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target')
    dt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Instead of this :

```
{
    "weight": 19.23,
    "market": 11,
    "dt": "2022-06-09"
}
```

I would like to post in this form :

```
{
    "weight": 0.1923,
    "market_symbol": "ABC/USD",
    "market_type": "xyz",
    "market_exchange_exid": "my_exchange",
    "dt": "2022-06-09"
}
```

To achieve this I created a class `ModelSerializer` and added the 3 custom fields that uniquely specify a market, as suggested in [Specifying fields explicitly](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly).

```
class TargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    market_symbol = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market_type = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    market_exchange = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = ('id', 'weight', 'dt', 'market_symbol', 'market_type', 'market_exchange')
```

However when I push the data it throws a `Bad Request 400`. How can I tell him to use this fields as a Foreign key selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices, I think the best approach might be to try overriding the `create` / `update` methods in your serializer, parse the serialized data for the symbol, type and exchange. Then get the Market object with that data and use that to create the Target object.

```
class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = ('id', 'symbol', 'type', 'exchange',)


class TargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    market_symbol = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, write_only=True)
    market_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, write_only=True)
    market_exchange = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, write_only=True)
    market = MarketSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = ('id', 'weight', 'dt', 'market', 'market_symbol', 'market_type', 'market_exchange')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        market = get_object_or_404(
            Market, 
            symbol=validated_data['market_symbol'],
            type=validated_data['market_type'],
            exchange=validated_data['market_exchange'],
        )
        return Target.objects.create(market=market, weight=validated_data['weight'], dt=validated_data['dt'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried and it says this `AttributeError: 'Target' object has no attribute 'market_symbol'`. And also this `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `market_symbol` on serializer `TargetSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Target` instance. Original exception text was: 'Target' object has no attribute 'market_symbol'.`

Comment: What are you posting to the end point? And can you provide the full traceback for the errors?

Comment: I updated the question with the informations. Also I notice that despite the error an object is created

Comment: ah, sorry, i messed up, one sec